# Сравнение двух одномерных массивов

Tags: c#

Помогите сравнить 2 массива. Оба одномерные, надо узнать , в каком массиве меньше единиц.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var k = richTextBox1.Lines.Count(s => s == "0" );
    var k1 = richTextBox1.Lines.Count(s => s == "1");
    textBox1.Text = "Количество нулей и единиц = " + k;
    textBox2.Text = "Количество нулей и единиц = " + k1; 

}
```

Comment: А разве данный пример не даёт ответ?

Comment: Если в массиве только '0' и '1' то можно 'Sum' использовать.

Comment: Данный пример - это один массив, а как добавить второй и через сумму сравнить где меньше единиц?

Comment: @slippyk: Там у ТС не числа, а строки. Так что идея со сложением не взлетит так просто.

Comment: плакать хочется, простите